# Implement an xml parser for the following xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
<day>
    <date>October 19</date>
        <job>
            <value>xyz</value>
            <time>5:30</time>
        </job>
        <job>
            <value>abc</value>
            <time>6:30</time>
        </job>
</day>

<day>
    <date>October 20</date>
        <job>
            <value>xyz</value>
            <time>5:30</time>
        </job>
        <job>
            <value>abc</value>
            <time>6:30</time>
        </job>
</day>
```

I am new to development I need an xml parse implementation with table view. The parser should be such that, it has to show the "value" in table cells, and there should be sections based on the date. Oct 2 section will show "job" of that date and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBXML is the best choise because is fast and is memory-efficient, but if you need parse a lot of items I recommend libxml2 – SAX because you can parse while download and display the results.
Take a look to [this page](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) to compare parsers

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use TBXML which is a very light and easy to understand XML parser.

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

You also have to modelise your data (Day with Array of Jobs?).
You can also parse the XML with TBXML and fill some NSMutableDictionnary of "date", and for each "date" you will have an array of "jobs".